# Deploying yeoman fullstack app to elastic beanstalk

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, angular-fullstack

I'm looking to use elastic beanstalk for my [yeoman angular-fullstack app](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack), though I'm having some trouble when deploying to elastic beanstalk.

So far I have:

- my local yeoman angular fullstack (https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) ready to go.
- Eb Cli 3.0 installed and ready to go (if needed)
- Elastic beanstalk running a custom meanstack ami
  (https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00GXYEEA4)

Though I'm a bit confused on the next steps. I've tried uploading /dist to my server via the elastic beanstalk online interface, but got errors... :/

> Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more
>   information, see troubleshooting documentation.

I'm open to using the eb cli, though my git repo contains all my development resources and the dist folder, so figured it would probably explode if I pushed my whole repo.

Anywhos if anyone knows how to successfully deploy a yeoman app to an eb server I would be extremely grateful. I certainly can just use an ec2 server myself, but wouldn't mind to know how to use eb instead.

Thanks all!

Comment: Have you looked around at the log files in /var/log/?  There are a few there with names like eb-* that might have more information about what went wrong.  Just use "eb ssh" to log in to your instance.

Comment: Yeah poked around in there, only one I found was launch related info from what looked like initially spinning up the server. Other than that coming up short.

Answer (score 0):

If we deploy the production build  to particular server we have to done some pre-configurations. For example if deploy the dist folder in an apache server we have to add the following .htaccess configuration. without this .htaccess configuration angularjs routs will not work, means [host]/login will return 404 error

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

elastic beanstalk is a scalable architecture for deploying web applications. i am not familiar with eb. I think in eb also we have to do some pre configuration for deploying dist folder (angular production build)